# Differences between sympy and lambda()

Tags: lambda, sympy

I have been trying to optimize a piece of code originally written using Sympy (it is correct but slow). I substituted the equations by `lambda()` functions (it is much faster). However, the output is not exactly the same. It may seem like a minor deviation, but to me, it makes a difference. I will highly appreciate any idea or suggestion about how to make both results identical. Please, see below the code:

```
# --------- Parameters ----------------
s_1_value = 0.9
s_2_value = 1.2
s_eq_pre = 11.628616990912533
history = 471.88639640808105

# --------- Sympy ----------------
t = sympy.Symbol('t', positive = True)
s_1, s_2 = sympy.symbols('s_1 s_2', real = True)
s_eq = + 6.11513442504139 * s_1 ** 3 + 0.764837815685049 * s_1 + 0.0319169512850692 * s_2 ** 3 + 0.00409678596174992 * s_2 + 0.0837906906442538
exponential = sympy.exp(1.73847894065589 * t) * sympy.exp(-1.74850463949595 * t)

s_eq_cur = s_eq.subs([(s_1, s_1_value), (s_2, s_2_value)])
DELTA = (s_eq_pre - s_eq_cur) * (1 / exponential.subs(t, history))

print("sympy: ", DELTA)


# --------- lambda ----------------
s_eq = lambda s_1, s_2: + 6.11513442504139 * s_1 ** 3 + 0.764837815685049 * s_1 + 0.0319169512850692 * s_2 ** 3 + 0.00409678596174992 * s_2 + 0.0837906906442538
exponential = lambda t: mpmath.exp(1.73847894065589 * t) * mpmath.exp(-1.74850463949595 * t)
DELTA_ = lambda s_eq_pre_, s_eq_cur_: (s_eq_pre_ - s_eq_cur_) * (1 / exponential(history))

s_eq_cur = s_eq(s_1_value, s_2_value)
DELTA = DELTA_(s_eq_pre, s_eq_cur)

print("lambda: ", DELTA)
```

and the output:

```
sympy:   718.832531350073
lambda:  718.83253135012
```

Thank you...

Comment: You can increase the mpmath precision.

Comment: Consider using `mpmath.exp((1.73847894065589-1.74850463949595) * t)` (or even the `math.exp`.  `mpmath.exp(1.73847894065589 * t)` is a very large value, too large in fact for python floats. (float64).

Comment: While Python allows you to assign a `lambda` function to a variable name (as you do), it's considered better form to use the `def s_eq():` function syntax.  Code will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the ability of SymPy to auto-simplify the expression of the lambda before evaluation:

```
>>> exp(1.73847894065589 * t) * exp(-1.74850463949595 * t)
exp(-0.01002569884006*t)
>>> 1/_.subs(t, history)
113.407882233341
```

That single function evaluates slightly differently than the product of the two functions. If you don't want this to happen you either have to use an unevaluate-Mul for the expression or you can make your lambda a 2-arg lambda and supply the function you want to use for `exp` at the call of the function:

```
>>> e1, e2 = sympy.exp(1.73847894065589 * t), sympy.exp(-1.74850463949595 * t)
>>> uneval = lambda x: Mul(e1, e2, evaluate=False).subs(t, x)
>>> two_args = lambda e, t: e(1.73847894065589 * t)*e(-1.74850463949595 * t)
>>> 1/uneval(history)
113.407882233349
>>> 1/two_args(sympy.exp, history)
113.407882233349
>>> 1/two_args(mpmath.exp, history)
113.407882233349
```